# Maven error when downloading latest 2.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

Suddenly i encounter the following error when trying to download the latest 2.1-SNAPSHOT from the configured snapshot repository:

> [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.javalite:javalite-common:2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven.oracle.com (https://maven.oracle.com): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Authorization Required.
>   [WARNING] Failure to transfer org.javalite:javalite-common:2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from https://maven.oracle.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven.oracle.com has elapsed or updates are forced.

I use the exact same repository configuration in my pom.xml as mentioned [here](http://javalite.io/activejdbc#getting-the-latest-version) and didn't change there anything since months.
I also cleared my local repository cache, without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the section for pulling in releases. However you are trying to download a snapshot. Pease refer to this section:http://javalite.io/activejdbc#getting-latest-snapshot-versions

UPDATE:

I found the reason for this. The Oracle repository was recently added to the ActiveJDBC project in order to pull the Oracle driver, see the pom here:http://repo.javalite.io/org/javalite/activejdbc-root/2.1-SNAPSHOT/activejdbc-root-2.1-20180409.170113-54.pom. 
Unfortunately due to the way Maven works, the projects will inherit this repo. Oracle did not make it easy for people, being a commercial company. They require that you register an account  and properly configure creds to access their repo. This is why you get the "Not authorized" message. However, this is  just a warning and does not really do any damage. If you want to ignore this repo, you can follow advice given here: [How do you configure maven to ignore repositories specified in POM files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503829/how-do-you-configure-maven-to-ignore-repositories-specified-in-pom-files)

Comment: As mentioned i'm getting that error where i'm already using the Javalite repo for snapshots, and not a release.

Comment: Apparently you have a misconfigured oracle repo, which is unrelated to JavaLite.

Comment: Ok then it seems that it has nothing to do with Javalite. The funny thing is that i've nowhere configured an oracle repo. That's why i do not understand why maven tries to download javalite-common from there.

Comment: new issue was created: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues/706

Comment: The warning has been resolved. You can pull a new snapshot now.